# Trouble with template and stringstream

Tags: c++

I want to create function that will convert string to number using `stringstream`. If i suppose that my number will be `int`:

```
int stringToNumber(string str)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    int num;
    ss >> num;
    return num;
}
cout << stringToNumber("182") + 100 << endl; //282
```

This code works correctly. But when i try to use template i get an error. Below is my code:

```
template <typename number>
number stringToNumber(string str)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    number num;
    ss >> num;
    return num;
}
```

The errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘stringToNumber(const char [4])’
     cout << stringToNumber("125") + 280 << endl;
                                 ^
main.cpp:17:33: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:6:8: note: template<class number> number stringToNumber(std::string)
 number stringToNumber(string str)
        ^
main.cpp:6:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:33: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘number’
     cout << stringToNumber("125") + 280 << endl;
```

Comment: Well you don't tell it what type to use. You'ld need to call it like `stringToNumber<int>("125");`. There's no way it can deduce that for you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template argument cannot be deduced that way. You have to provide the template argument explicitly:

```
std::cout << stringToNumber<int>("125");
```